# Is it possible to mock the File.ls in elixir?

Tags: mocking, elixir

Python allows you to even mock the `os.listdir` for testing purposes. Can you do the same thing using mock libraries for Elixir ? An example would be nice.

Comment: Did you try mocking it with https://github.com/jjh42/mock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [many mocking libraries](https://hex.pm/packages?_utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=mock&sort=downloads) for Elixir, most are based on the [meck](https://hex.pm/packages/meck) library for erlang.
[This blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/) by Jose Valim covers alternatives to mocking frameworks in favor of simple stubs, protocols or callback functions.

[Mock](https://github.com/jjh42/mock):

This is a good option if you want to globally stub out a function that may be called from code you can't control (3rd party package or standard library). The downside is that your tests cannot be run asynchronously when using this approach.

```
 use ExUnit.Case, async: false
 import Mock

 test "test_name" do
    with_mock HTTPotion, [get: fn(_url) -> "<html></html>" end] do
      HTTPotion.get("http://example.com")
      # Tests that make the expected call
      assert called HTTPotion.get("http://example.com")
    end
  end
```

[Stubr](https://github.com/leighshepperson/stubr):

This library is slightly different in that it assists you in creating a stub for an existing module that can then be passed as a parameter to other functions:

```
test "create a stub of Timex.now/0 and defer on all other functions" do
  fixed_time = Timex.to_datetime({2999, 12, 30})

  timex_stub = Stubr.stub!([now: fn -> fixed_time end], module: Timex, auto_stub: true)

  assert timex_stub.now == fixed_time
  assert timex_stub.before?(fixed_time, timex_stub.shift(fixed_time, days: 1))
end
```

[Syringe](https://github.com/skylerparr/syringe):

This library uses the `inject` macro to allow you to swap out a module dependency when running tests. It requires that you modify your code, but in return you can run tests asynchronously.

```
defmodule MyThing do
  def do_mine_things do
    1 + 2
  end
end

defmodule MyModule do
  use Injector

  inject MyThing, as: Mine

  def do_things do
    Mine.do_mine_things
  end
end

defmodule MyModuleTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  import Mocker

  test "Mine must be called" do
    mock(MyThing)
    assert MyModule.do_things == nil
    intercept(MyThing, :do_mine_things, nil, with: fn() -> "my mocked return" end)
    assert MyModule.do_things == "my mocked return"
    assert was_called(MyThing, :do_mine_things, nil) == twice # success
  end
end
```

[Mockery](https://github.com/appunite/mockery)

Similar to syringe, your code must be modified to use a dynamic proxy for tests.  When using this library you declare dependencies with module attributes:

```
defmodule MyApp.Controller do
  @service Mockery.of(MyApp.UserService)

  def all do
    @service.users()
  end
end
```

Then in a test:

```
# mock MyApp.UserService.users/0
mock MyApp.UserService, [users: 0], "mock"
assert MyApp.Controller.all() == "mock"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was missing the ability to easily mock any function within Elixir, I have decided to write the Hex package [MecksUnit](https://github.com/archan937/mecks_unit). It allows you to mock module functions elegantly without any hassle.

```
defmodule MecksUnit.FooTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  use MecksUnit.Case

  defmock List do
    def wrap(:foo_test), do: ~w(MecksUnit Bar Test)
  end

  mocked_test "parallel compiling" do
    task =
      Task.async(fn ->
        assert [:foo, :bar] == List.wrap([:foo, :bar])
        assert ~w(MecksUnit Bar Test) == List.wrap(:foo_test)
        assert called(List.wrap(:foo_test))
      end)

    Task.await(task)
  end
end
```

Within the code example, I have mocked the `List.wrap/1` function. The advantages of using MecksUnit versus [Mock](https://github.com/jjh42/mock):

1. it is possible to run the tests asynchronously ^^ (note: the mocked modules are isolated per test)
2. defining mocked functions is much more readable / natural

See also [my Elixir forum post about MecksUnit](https://elixirforum.com/t/mecksunit-elegantly-mock-module-functions-in-async-exunit-tests/19333). Please note that you can also assert functions calls. Being easy and unobtrusive has been MecksUnits main objective. Hope that it can help you out. If so, good luck!